# Symfony2 Doctrine, setup a page with many to many self referencing relationship

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, many-to-many, self-reference

I have tried following the instructions on Doctrines manuals:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-self-referencing

I'm trying to setup a pages entity, which has many subPages and I would also like to be able to access a pages parentPage.

Following the instructions above I am told by symfony2 that I need to setup a "use" due to a semantic error.

Could anybody instruct me on what to do to allow me to do this as I am quite stuck.

Sample code is:

```
namespace Pages\Bundle\PageBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Page
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Page")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Pages\Bundle\PageBundle\Entity\PageRepository")
 */
class Page
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->subPages = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->parentPages = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Page", mappedBy="subPages")
     **/
    private $parentPages;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Page", inversedBy="parentPages")
     * @JoinTable(name="sub_pages",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="parent_page_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="sub_page_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     **/
    private $subPages;
```

...
(other variables follow but are content / metas)

Error response when running is:

```
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@ManyToMany" in property
Pages\Bundle\PageBundle\Entity\Page::$parentPages was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?
```

Comment: What are the errors you are getting? any code we can look at? Kind of vague here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using `@ORM\ManyToMany` instead of just `@ManyToMany`

(and also `@ORM\JoinTable`)

Comment: This happens all the time when copying and pasting from the doctrine docs.